# Convert an InArgument<T> into type T

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

I'm making a custom activity for a workflow, but am having trouble with InArguments.  I have InArguments of type String that I want to use as Strings in the code, but I cannot find a way to do this conversion.  I've searched online but couldn't find a solution.

I'm pretty sure I should be doing this inside the "get-set" when the variable is created but don't know how exactly to do this conversion.

Here is where I create the variable:

```
[Input("Job Name")]
[Default("BMS_ExtractTransformLoad")]
public InArgument<String> JobName { get; set; }
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it this way.

```
var jobName = JobName.Get(activityContext);
```